# Pyvis - Title Render on Hover

Tags: networkx, pyvis

I've visualized an Application & how APIs interact with it using NetworkX & Pyvis
I've put a fair amount of information in the "Title" property to show in the yellow box on hover.
(JSON / SQL / C# / Python etc)
Is there anyway to Lint & color the title property
so using SQL as an example instead of
`SELECT * FROM A`
we get the following with Keywords colored like in any editor

```sql
SELECT *
FROM A
```

& either;

1. Make the yellow box scrollable so you can read all of the box?
2. Or on click open the title box in another window?

Thanks